# Unable to get quote items programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, quoteitem

In order to send all user quote items to my other middle ware database I am getting quote items, but I am not getting it

I placed a `.php` file in my Magento root as `send.php` and then Included below script.

```
<?php
require_once("app/Mage.php");
Mage::app('default'); 


$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();

foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($item);
    /*if ($item->getParentItemId()) {
        continue;
    }*/
}
```

But I am not getting any quote items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following line after **Mage::app('default');**

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
```

Your code looks like

```
require_once("app/Mage.php");
Mage::app('default');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
```

Comment: Excellent. It works, But why?

Comment: @Sohel ..initialize session

Comment: You need to Initialize frontend session.